# Positioning middle of multiple images

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a photo album.  I'm having a problem when you're viewing the website in a smaller window, a photo will just not fit on the right and leaving a big gap there

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" />
    </a>
    ....
</div>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    background: #000;
}

#gallery {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding:0 12.5px;
}

#gallery a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 12.5px 25px 12.5px;
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
    width:225px;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
#gallery a img {
    height:150px;
    width:225px;
    display:none;
}
```

You can see an working version here: http://codepen.io/Dirkandries/full/hLxft

How can I always align center all of the images?

I have already tried `margin: 0 auto;`, only it does not seem to work

Comment: Why do you want to poison your HTML? What did it ever do to you?

Comment: @Shmiddty, amusing - but this is a community site, and it would be better to edit obvious mistakes than make fun of them

Comment: @freefaller Lighten up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` on the links instead of floating them left, then use `text-align:center` on the gallery wrapper.

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jIfLh**

```
#gallery {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding:0 12.5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#gallery a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 12.5px 25px 12.5px;
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
    width:225px;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: i thought text-align only works on p elements but your telling me it works on all inline elements!? if thats true thats a mind blower for me!

Comment: You're correct, inline content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align